# PDO and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, pdo

I want to set a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in this function.

How i can make this?

```
public function insert($table, $values) {           

    try {

        foreach ($values as $key => $value)
            $field_names[] = $key . ' = :' . $key;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " SET " . implode(', ', $field_names);

        $stmt = self::$PDO->prepare($sql);

        foreach ($values as $key => $value)
            $stmt->bindValue(':' . $key, $value);

        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $exception) {

        die($exception->getMessage());

    }

}
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: JFYI, [this code is vulnerable to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/lame_update)

Comment: Thanks. Can jou help me. I dont kmow hou to start.